# Relación muchos a muchos en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy empezando a desarrollar un proyecto personal en Rails (estoy aprendiendo). Tengo un modelo llamado **Album** y otro llamado **Genre**. Un album puede tener varios géneros, y un género puede tener muchos álbumes.

¿Cómo puedo representar eso en la base de datos? Porque, por ejemplo, cuando tengo una relación `belongs_to :modeloalquepertenece`, en la tabla del modelo agrego un campo: `t.integer :modeloalquepertenece_id`

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo con relaciones muchos a muchos.

De ante mano, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta la encontré en este sitio: http://www.elclubdelprogramador.com/2012/05/20/rails-active-record-avanzado-asociaciones-vi-parte/

Básicamente debo crear una migración que relaciones los dos modelos.